# Heroku /Sidekiq error when kill/retry job - 403 Forbidden - Attack prevented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku

I use Sidekiq on my heroku app and when I want to kill a job or retry, it will lead to 403 forbidden page with an error:

```
WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin
```

My heroku app: http://myapp.herokuapp.com
My domain name where it does not work: https://www.myapp.my

In sidekiq [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring), I found this to fix the error adding to the routes.rb but it does not help: 
Sidekiq::Web.set :session_secret, Rails.application.secrets[:secret_key_base]

My session_store.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

I guess there is an issue with the ssl. I found [this solution](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1289#issuecomment-232330804) for nginx.conf but how to set it up on heroku to test if this help?

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host 'my-host.com';
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Or any other solution how to solve the 403 forbidden?

Edit: My routes

```
  require 'sidekiq/web'

  authenticate :admin do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
```

It does work on localhost but not in production

Edit #2: If I switch off the https and let my app to be on http, it does work so how to tell my app/sidekiq to use https?

> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
> This will tell your application that the original request came in
>   using https even though the request from nginx to unicorn is http.

But how to do it on heroku?

Comment: How are you sending the command to stop/retry a job? I suspect that the issue is not related to SSL,but to csfr_authenticity token not passed

Comment: I am sending it through the UI https://www.myapp.my/sidekiq. In localhost, it does work without any issue

Comment: I edited the comment It's due to the https redirection. With http:// it does work. How to tell the sidekiq to use https?

Comment: Did you try also the second option suggested by https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#forbidden `
Sidekiq::Web.use(::Rack::Protection, { use: :authenticity_token, logging: true, message: "Didn't work!" })`

Comment: You can have a look at www.sourcediver.org/blog/2015/07/01/rack-protection-and-nginx/ referred in an issue on the GitHub source https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2560

Comment: thanks mabe02 but the solution is for nginx and not heroku - I asked heroku support and the solution won't work there so looking for something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced same problem on heroku.

Solution for custom domains;

- You need to force ssl your rails app in config file. Because heroku app use default https scheme for app url. If you do not force it, it will use different schemes in forwarding requests. 
  `config/environments/production.rb`

  ```
  # Force ssl
  config.force_ssl = true
  ```
- If you are using free dynos on heroku, you can not use ssl feature and you should use heroku app url to access sidekiq web ui `https://your-app.herokuapp.com/sidekiq`

Comment: Oh it works! I use free dynos so accessing the app in herokuapp domain is good enough solution. Thanks!

Comment: I need certain requests to not be ssl and I have this controlled by a before_action in my application controller. How do I force just sidekiq/web to use https? - the web interface works great but when I press a button like "Retry All" it tried to use an http connection for some reason.