# Where to add proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku

Where/how to add nginx configuration `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` on Heroku - rails app?

I encouraged this issue: [Heroku /Sidekiq error when kill/retry job - 403 Forbidden - Attack prevented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427511/heroku-sidekiq-error-when-kill-retry-job-403-forbidden-attack-prevented) and it seems that the only way to solve it is to add the configuration proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme into my app but I couldn't find any help how to do so.

Comment: was there a solution to this?